# How to get Kendo UI PopOver ListView selected values

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

How to get Kendo UI PopOver Checkbox ListView selected values. I have used [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/popover/index.html) example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for checked items inside the ListView like this for example:

```
$('[data-role="listview"] :radio:checked').map(function () {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    console.log($(this).closest('label').text())
  }
});
```